# Error in integrating twitter in android

Tags: android

when i run my apps i am getting error

```
09-14 16:33:52.854: W/System.err(380): 401:Authentication credentials (http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
09-14 16:33:52.864: W/System.err(380): error - Read-only application cannot POST
```

I've changed the access to read, write and direct access 
but still the above error says read only application.

My apps is not showing the updates is there ant way to refesh the eclipse or application completely ..it is not taking and showing the updates when I run android application.

Comment: This may solve your issue too..setting callback url..http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5324503#5324503

Comment: @user1508671 Are you using which library to post tweet on twitter from your android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there ant way to refesh the eclipse or application completely

To refresh project, you can clean project by Eclipse -> Project -> Clean -> Select project from check box and radio button to "Clean projects selected below" and ok button.

Log shows you are missing something in request, its very obvious.

Your error is understandable but whether you trying to integrate twitter in app using WebView / browser or straight away (which is not recommendable), using any 3rd party library and if yes then which library you using, is unclear.

You can refer these following tutorials available on internet to integrate twitter in your application.

Using only one library twitter4j to handle oAuth and make tweets both

1. http://blog.blundell-apps.com/sending-a-tweet/
2. http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html

Using two or more third party libraries for oAuth and tweeting tasks

1. http://blog.tarams.com/?p=212
2. http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application
3. http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/,

Thanks,